# how to install androidsdk documentation in android studio, where can I download it?

Tags: android

how to installing androidsdk in android studio
I tried to install it but can't find where it is
any help would be appreciated

Comment: [Adding SDK Packages](https://android-doc.github.io/sdk/installing/adding-packages.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open Android Studio,

- Click Tools > SDK Manager.
- In the SDK Platforms tab, select Android 11 (or any other SDK version you want).
- In the SDK Tools tab, select Android SDK Build-Tools 30 (or higher).
- Click OK to begin the install.

You can read more [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/setup-sdk).